# Function that it always returns a QTY of 0 instead of a calculation

Tags: sql-server

I am using a CAST function in SQL and one works and one doesn't. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT
CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY AS Order_QTY
, CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY
, CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE
, CAST(((CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY - CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY) * CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE) AS decimal(15, 2)) AS Total_Order_Dollars -- Doesnt Work
, CAST((CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY - CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY) AS decimal(15, 2)) AS Quantity_To_Ship -- Works perfectly.
```

What am I doing wrong in the first "CAST" Function that it always returns a QTY of 0 instead of a calculation?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the result? We can't help you if we don't know what the problem is. Sample data, as well as the output and expected output would be nice.

Comment: If you're getting the result `0`, then either `CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY - CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY` or `CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE` has a value `0`. *On a different note, I strongly recommend using aliases for your (table) objects. It'll make your queries much more succinct, and therefore more readable. So, for an object like `CUST_ORDER_LINE` you could use the alias `COL`.*

Comment: CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY = 200
CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY = 100
CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE = 2.00
Formula: (200-100)*2.00 Result: 200.00

Comment: I would love to use aliases but I don't know how to set them up.

Comment: Of course it returns 0. Look at your formula. Any number minus itself is 0, then multiply that by anything and it will be 0.

Comment: `CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY - CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY` this will return 0, which means you're multiplying `CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE` by zero.

Comment: Your line that "works" doesn't work either because it will also always be 0.

Comment: For aliases...https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was the mistake that I could not see.
The formula needs to be: , CAST(((CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY - CUST_ORDER_LINE.TOTAL_SHIPPED_QTY) * CUST_ORDER_LINE.UNIT_PRICE) AS decimal(15, 2)) AS Total_Order_Dollars

Comment: Yet another readon why aliases are a good idea. It turns this wall of text into something way more legible.

Comment: Indeed, `CAST(((COL.ORDER_QTY - COL.ORDER_QTY) * COL.UNIT_PRICE) AS decimal(15, 2))` makes the "problem" very easy to spot.

Comment: CAST((COL.ORDER_QTY - COL.TOTAL_SHIPPED_QTY) AS decimal(15, 2)) AS Quantity_To_Ship
, CAST(((COL.ORDER_QTY - COL.TOTAL_SHIPPED_QTY) * COL.UNIT_PRICE) AS decimal(15, 2)) AS Total_Order_Dollars

Comment: Thank you veryone for the help!